# Why this LEFT OUTER JOIN is not including all the Primary Keys from the Left

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, outer-join

The customers table has total 1000 customers of which 1500 placed orders in FY 2016. But we want to display all the customers with their total number of orders in FY 2016 whether a customer placed an order in that FY or not. But the following query in SQL Server 2012 is displaying only 1490.

What we may be missing here?

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, count(*) AS TotalOrders
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
WHERE o.FiscalYear = '2016'
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```

**UPDATE**:

The following query returns only 1 more record (1491) - still missing 9 more records.

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, count(*) AS TotalOrders
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
                   AND o.FiscalYear = '2016'
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```

Comment: The where clause is applied after the join. So the join is returning null values for customers without orders.  but then since those customers have no orders fiscalYear is not equal to 2016 so the records are being excluded.  To correct move the limiting criteria involved with outer joins to the join criteria so the limit is imposed along with the join.

Comment: Your total record count should be 1000 (customers) the sum of count should be 1500.  The only possible variance to sum being less than 1500 is you've deleted customers and orphaned orders.  Or your count for 2016 orders of 1500 is wrong to begin with.  does `SELECT * from orders where customerID not in (Select customerID from customers) and FiscalYear = '2016'` give you some records?

Comment: Yeah I would start checking things like: Is your FiscalYear actually distinct "2016" for all records? Are there potential for typos? How are records marked deleted (bit/int flag)?

Comment: What does `select count(distinct customerid), count(*) from orders where fiscalyear = '2016'` return?

Comment: Do all orders have a customerID?  are some null/blank or non-existent in the customer table?

Comment: On a side note: Is `FiscalYear` a varchar column or why do you compare with `'2016'` (a string) and not `2016` (a number).

Comment: @xQbert It's a legacy app with no FK. After reading all the comments I have read so far the issue seems to be related to data. For example, the query in your question gives me some records. I first need to check all the items suggested by the users so far. I'm glad I posted the question so I know where to look.

Comment: if no keys then the reason you have the number difference is you have orphaned order record (Customer records have been removed and thus the order can't be tied to the customer.  you could use a FULL outer join instead of a left to see some of those records w/o a customer. and it should get your count to the 1500.

Comment: @ xQbert You are correct. Issue resolved - related to data, orphaned record etc. For the benefits of other users you may want to convert your comments to a `Response` along with any query syntax suggestions - and I would mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

You `where` clause is turning the `left outer join` into an `Inner join`.

Change it to `AND`:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, count(o.CustomerID) AS TotalOrders
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o
    ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
    AND o.FiscalYear = '2016'     -- Here
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that I had tried including `Where` condition in the `LEFT JOIN` but it increased only the total record by 1. Still missing 9 more.

Comment: @nam It's not the query. Can you check how many distinct CustomerID do you have in the Customers table right now?

Comment: There is another mistake in the query: `COUNT(*)` should be `COUNT(o.CustomerID)` or the like in order to count 0, not 1, for customers without orders.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - Quite right. Updated. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

The correct SQL is:

```
SELECT c.CustomerID, count(o.CustomerID) AS TotalOrders,
       sum(count(o.CustomerID)) over () as TotalTotalOrders
FROM Customers c LEFT JOIN
     Orders o
     ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID AND o.FiscalYear = '2016'
GROUP BY c.CustomerID;
```

`TotalTotalOrders` should be all the orders (or at least the ones with valid customer ids).

Answer (score 0):

This will list all customers, whether or not they have any orders *regardless of the year in which the order was placed*. The `sum` will then count all orders that were placed in 2016, ignore the rest, and return an intenger (i.e. it will never be null).

```
SELECT
   c.CustomerID
  ,sum(case when o.FiscalYear = '2016' then 1 else 0 end)  AS TotalOrders
FROM Customers c
LEFT JOIN Orders o
 ON c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
GROUP BY c.CustomerID
```

Comment: Eh, it won't perform as well as @Gurwinder's answer, but it provides more flexibility should your requirements change.